# Sometimes HTML video doesn't autoplay after loading

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Sometimes the HTML video on the topmost portion of [my site](http://toda.net) doesn't run even though after it has been completely downloaded. I am using Safari 5.0.6 on iMac. On other browsers as well, sometimes it works fine and at times, it only starts working when I refresh the page.

Can you guess what may be causing this ?, or how I could try fixing this ?

Comment: Hey, old question I know, but I've viewed your site and refreshed it a ton of times and you video always starts.... I'm having a similar problem where sometimes my video just doesn't autoplay (1 in 5/6 times).  Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 7):

Got the same issue in chrome, autoplay can be emulated by the next way (using jQuery's selector):

```
<video ..... oncanplay="$(this)[0].play()" >...</video>
```

Comment: thanks, this helped, but in javascript you can do:

video.oncanplay = video.play;

Also, instead of using jquery, and getting the dom element, do this: 
oncanplay="this.play()"

Answer (score 1):

Well, I opened your site on my browsers. It's working just fine on Chrome 15 and Firefox 7 [Windows7]. May be you should try it on newer browsers.

Comment: Likewise: Chrome 15 in Fedora 14, seems to work fine. I would like to point out that not only is Safari in general as well as your specific version (5.0.6) a bit dated, but the HTML5 video API surely isn't considered "mature" yet. Getting closer everyday, but not mature.